# Upload a photo to web service with phonegap

Tags: ajax, cordova, base64

OK, So I am able to take a picture with the phone's camera and view it inside an *img*, now I want to upload it through a web service that receives a

```
<File> base64Binary </File>.
```

This is how I set the image:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) 
{ 
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage'); 
  smallImage.style.display = 'block'; 
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 
}
```

And this is how I try to send it:

```
       var ima=document.getElementById("smallImage").src;

       var soapRequest ='<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-          instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+   
            '<soap:Body>'+
            '<InsertFileInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+

             '<File>'+ima+'</File>'+
             '<FileName>sldkq.jpg</FileName>'+
             '<Description>Photo</Description>'+
             '<Code>'+CodeFile+'</Code>'+

             '</InsertFileInfo>'+
            '</soap:Body>'+
            '</soap:Envelope>';            

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
            });


    function processSuccess(data, status, req) 
    { 

        if (status == "success")
        {
            alert("sent"); 
        }

    }

    function processError(data, status, req) 
    {
    alert('error'+data.state);
        //alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
    }
```

Then some minutes pass and I finally get the processError function message.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: What  is error? I hope `wsUrl` is defined

Comment: yes, wsUrl is defined.

Comment: and the error just says: "function(){return n}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to solve it. If anyone has this issue: the variable 'ima' was requesting for the .src of an img but that didn't work. So I used something else to store the base64 value of the picture:

`window.localStorage.setItem("CodePhoto", imageData);`

And I read it inside the request like this:

```
var codePhoto = window.localStorage.getItem("CodigoFoto");
```

And Finally put it inside the

```
 <File></File>
```

like this:

```
 ...'<File>'+codePhoto+'</File>'+...
```